# Should validation be on business models or view models?

Tags: validation, n-tier-architecture

I am trying to figure out where to put validation in my N-Tier Asp.net MVC application

On the one hand I feel like validation should be in the business layer with the business objects themselves.  This means that when validation rules change I only have to change it in one spot (e.g. right now user display names can be anything but now I want the names to be a minimum of 5 characters and no symbols).  This makes it simple to understand where to find validation rules and makes it easier to keep validation rules consistent across processes.

On the other hand I also feel like validation should be on the view models because sometimes you need validation for a specific process data that will not be needed on the business object.  For example, when a user changes their password you want them to enter their password in the form twice so they don't make a mistake in their password and fail login.  Your User business object doesn't need two password fields because it doesn't make sense, as you only need two passwords when changing your current password (or creating a new account).  Therefore, it makes sense to me to put validation on view models to make sure process specific validations are run.  The downside to this is now when validation rules change you have the potential of MANY spots that this needs to be updated (you have to change the rules on every view model that deals with users).

The 3rd option is to split the validation between your business objects and view models where it makes sense.  The problem with this is I can see it getting hard to realize if a validation rule is triggering due to the view model validation failure or business object validation failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made some good considerations. Personally, I have previously validated in the view and controller layers, but have recently come to realize that this may not be the best approach. While it does make sense to do it in the controller, it can indeed become a repetitive task as you also mentioned.

I would vouch for view and business layer. Some things are just good to catch in the view layer before sending a request to the server. For example, it would make sense to check if there are field validation errors before uploading a 100 MB large file only to tell the user that they made a typo. Obviously, view validation should always be backed up by server side validation.

The concept referred to as "fat models" puts as much validation within the business layer as possible, which has many advantages;

- Your code will be reusable as it will be wrapped inside every business object, rather than for specific controller actions for instance. Should you need to update a business rule, then you only need to update the related models and not every controller which uses those models (you also made a good point about this yourself)
- Your code will be more portable as it will be easier to switch to a different framework for instance if you do not have a business layer that relies on controllers to enforce business logic
- Controllers will be easier to understand, hence why the flow in your application will be easier to follow, and new developers will probably find it easier to get up to speed
- Writing a validation rule once or twice is less error phone than writing it repeatedly
- Debugging and testing is likely to be easier

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend your third option. Split the validation as appropriate.

Using your example of typing the new password twice (to ensure it is typed correctly), it does not make sense to send both passwords along to the business model (especially if this is a distributed/web application) to check that they are the same, when your view model can easily compare the two. Other constraints, like username length, or required fields left blank, can easily be checked in the view when entered, and provide immediate feedback to the user.
Some things can't be validated in the view model, and need to be passed to the business model to be checked. One example is uniqueness of username.
One thing to be considered is that (especially in web development), is that client side validation is easier to bypass, so even if it is implemented, a malicious/mischevious user could still manage to submit bad data. To cover this case, it is best to check any critical validation constraints server-side. Of course, this leads back to the not-so-DRY problem that led you to this question...

**EDIT**:
The primary reason i suggest for any separation is to provide the user with immediate feedback so that they can fix their submission as needed before it is actually submitted to the server for processing. If your dilemma is between one server-side location and another to place your validation code, then I say it is a matter of personal preference, but I recommend NOT separating it. In this case, it would be best to keep it all in one cohesive place, so that you know exactly where to go for updates and bug fixes.

Comment: By checking on the ViewModel I am still talking about checking server side.

Comment: Well, in that case, the last issue I raised is basically irrelevant.